# parLapply timeout option

Tags: r, parallel-processing, apply

I am running a function in parallel using `parLapply` as follows:

```
parLapply(cl, df, fun = SomeFunction)
```

where `cl` is a cluster I registered beforehand.

However the function execution is taking too long, and I would like to exit when the execution time takes too long.

I know that the `R.utils` package has the function `withTimeOut` which works nicely (when there are loops to exit from - and apply is in essence a loop).
Is there a similar function for the parallel apply family?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using foreach, which is very similar to parLapply, I can do:

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cl <- makeCluster(2))
foreach(ic = 1:5) %dopar% {
  withCallingHandlers({ 
    setTimeLimit(elapsed = 4, transient = TRUE)
    Sys.sleep(ic)
  }, error = function(e) stop("timeout"))
}
stopCluster(cl)
```